# How to delete the word "Applications" in the task bar, in the top left corner

Tags: gnome-shell

How do I delete the word "*Applications*" appearing in the task bar, in the top left corner as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "applications menu" extension installed. You can disable it from `gnome-tweaks` under **extensions** menu.
The default button is called "**Activities**" (should be there after disabling applications menu extension) you can hide it by installing [Hide activities button extension.](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/744/hide-activities-button/)